# Emploi du verbe dégénérer (maths)

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, verbes

> La solution dégénère vers la solution élémentaire...
>
> La solution se dégénère vers la solution élémentaire...
>
> La solution est dégénérée vers la solution élémentaire...

1. Trois formes : active, pronominale, passive. Lesquelles sont
   correctes ?
2. L'emploi de la préposition vers est approprié ?

Comment: L'équation, le cas, la valeur, l'objet géométrique peuvent être dégénérés. J'ai un peu de mal avec une "solution dégénérée", même si on le lit parfois.

Comment: Merci. En remplaçant solution avec l'équation (p. ex.) quelles phrases sont correctes ? Je pense que le verbe est pronominal. En plus, l'emploi de vers est-elle correcte ?

Comment: En anglais on utilise l'expression **degenerate solution**. Peut-être je suis influencé par l'anglais. Y a-t-il une alternative francisée ?

Comment: Wikipedia donne *un cas dégénéré* pour *degenerate solution*. J'écrirais: *L'équation dégénère en sa forme élémentaire.*

Comment: Je viens de modifier la question. Je pense que tu peux donner ta réponse qui en mérite:-)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Degenerate solution* est peu employé et Wikipedia lui préfère [degenerate case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_(mathematics)) qui correspond au français [cas dégénéré](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cas_d%C3%A9g%C3%A9n%C3%A9r%C3%A9).

J'ai un peu de mal avec une "solution dégénérée" qu'on lit aussi parfois car c'est plutôt une équation, un cas, une valeur, un objet géométrique qui peuvent être dégénérés.

*Se dégénérer* est rare et paraît peu adapté à une solution ou une équation qui ne se modifient pas toutes seules.

*Dégénérer* est le plus souvent intransitif, mais quand ce verbe a un complément d'objet indirect, la préposition est quasiment toujours ***en*** comme le montre ce graphique :

[image]

On pourra donc écrire :

> L'équation/la solution est dégénérée.
>
> L'équation dégénère en une forme élémentaire.

Answer (score 1):

Une solution ne peut pas être dégénérée vers, puisqu'elle a est déjà.
Une solution qui se dégénére, ne sonne pas juste non plus, parce que ce n'est pas la solution qui dégénère par elle même, mais un système de conditions qui fait dégénérer la solution.

Donc

> La solution dégénère vers la solution élémentaire (*si elle est en
> train de le faire*).
>
> La solution est dégénérée en la solution élémentaire (*si c'est un fait accompli*).